# 500: "Unable to read application configuration information"

Tags: google-drive-api

We are using the google-api-client gem in our Ruby on Rails project to access the Google Drive API methods and everything has been working great. However, we are sometimes receiving the following error response from the API when calling the drive.files.update or drive.files.insert methods:

{"code"=>500, "message"=>"Unable to read application configuration information"}

This error is not documented in the list of possible errors from the SDK, so I am not sure how I should go about it. Could you please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this error is transient, the best way is to have a retry strategy when that happens (simply retry the request 2 or 3 times before giving up).

It seems like some concurrency issue on the Drive side where a request to read your application's configuration times out. By experience with Google APIs - and web APIs in general - I can tell you that, even though the team will try to fix/improve these (btw I will repport the bug so they can investigate) errors like that will always happen once in a while even with a very low occurrence as concurrency, timeout and reliability issues on distributed, web-scale systems are extremely hard to resolve. The best to have fail-proof code on your side is to retry a few times on every single 500 and 503 errors from external web APIs.

If you really have time on your hands you could even implement an exponential backoff strategy where the time between each of your retries increases each time as described [in our documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/practices#implementing_exponential_backoff).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I initially assumed there was something missing from my application configuration or I am sometimes sending the wrong parameters. We will improve our mechanism for dealing with failed requests.